# Is there any tutorial around that is based on a full android application which entitled or works as Virtual Tour of a organization?

Tags: android

wondering if there is any full application tutorial and application includes, main screen with buttons which carry on user to another acitivity where a user can choose items from list which will navigate to another list to choose items from and at last a view showing   a picture and information about picture in text form.
more like a virtual tour of a college or university.
loads of tutorial around but related to games or depends on single activity,, but i want a full application tutorial please or someone's else project i can work on !

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have to ask myself why people are just not able to use a search engine like google, yahoo, bing, etc..

[Android projects hosted on Google (as an example)](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=android&btn=Search+projects)

Comment: mate i searched alot and am really good at searching but i probbly didn;t picked up the right wording to find the thing, i am going through this website, let see if i find thing i need, cheers anyway :)